# Palavra para quando um artigo de jornal está errado

Tags: palavra-para-ideia

Que palavra em PT-PT, e PT-BR, se usa para quando um jornal tem de publicar uma outra notícia a corrigir a primeira, e a pedir desculpas pelo engano?

Comment: Será por acaso "Errata" a palavra que procuras?

Comment: @JorgeB. Não. Imagina que um jornal publica uma notícia em que afirma algo pouco honroso sobre alguém. Mais tarde descobre-se que é falso. E o jornal publica outra peça, em que pede desculpa e repõe a verdade...

Comment: Se chama 'retratação'. 'Errata' é utilizado apenas quando ocorrem erros de informação sem que o jornal se obrigue a pedir desculpas.

Comment: @AndréLyra É isso mesmo! Obrigado

Comment: @AndréLyra faz uma resposta e eu aceito-a. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Há aqui uma pequena falha na pergunta: **artigo não é a mesma coisa que notícia**. Percebe-se bem a diferença [nesta página do Diários de Notícias](http://nescolas.dn.pt/nescolasv2/index.php?a=kitmedia&p=2_3).

Quando se escreve um artigo - *que, por definição, não é puramente factual* - a opinião do autor pode não ser bem aceite e alguém pode sentir que sua honra foi afetada negativamente. Isso não significa necessariamente que o artigo esteja errado, apenas que cada um tem a sua própria opinião.

Nesse caso, para retratar o "*erro*", há o que se chama [direito de resposta](http://www.clubedejornalistas.pt/?page_id=124) em que o "*lesado*" tem o direito de publicar uma peça de sua autoria contrapondo o que foi dito.

O direito de resposta pode também ser baseado numa notícia mas, como as notícias são escritas com [verdade jornalística](http://futurojornalismo.org/np4/45.html#.V9wwQPP6rVM), é mais raro acontecer.

Como o @centaurus disse, também há a [retratação](https://www.dicio.com.br/retratacao/) e o desmentido, mas eu nunca ouvi estas palavras como algo específico do jornalismo. São ambas situações que existem, embora se apliquem a qualquer coisa mas há uma diferença entre as duas no âmbito do jornalismo.

Uma notícia é feita com verdade jornalística, ou seja, com base nos fatos apurados até o momento em que se escreveu esta mesma notícia. Esses fatos podem mostrar-se incorretos no futuro, o que pode resultar num desmentido.

Se a notícia - *ou mesmo um artigo* - que se mostrar incorreta ou mal abordada ofender algo ou alguém, pode resultar numa retratação.

Agora há uma diferença básica entre direito de resposta, desmentido e retratação: o direito de resposta parte de quem foi visado na peça jornalística, enquanto os últimos partem do jornalista ou da edição.

Comment: Obrigado Eduardo! ;)

Comment: A retratação é uma peça jurídica e está no código penal brasileiro. O direito de resposta muitas vezes é negado pelo jornais, e por isso a retração através da justiça é a única maneira de conseguir o "direito" negado de resposta.

Comment: A pergunta diz respeito a Portugal e ao Brasil. Em Portugal o direito de resposta é jurídico e conseguido em Tribunal caso não se chegue a um acordo entre as partes

Answer (score 4):

Conforme citado por Jorge B em um comentário, **Errata** é o termo genérico usado principalmente em livros, mas também em jornais e qualquer outra publicação, para reconhecer e apresentar aos leitores qualquer informação errônea ou erro de tipografia em edição prévia.  **Quando o objetivo é corrigir a informação e desculpar-se por ter ofendido ou caluniado alguém, a errata torna-se uma retratação.**  Contudo, nem toda retratação impressa em um jornal refere-se a algo que foi publicado. Pode ser uma retratação pública, feita por um político, um artista, ou até mesmo um "simples mortal" como eu e você. Concluindo, a retratação pode ou não ser uma errata, assim como a errata pode ou não ser uma retratação.

> - [**Errata***](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errata) ou **corrigenda (plural de erratum ou corrigendum) são correções tipográficas anexadas a um livro, manual ou publicação. Geralmente são impressas nas páginas finais da obra ou em folha separada. Essas correções e outras que venham a ser descobertas serão incorporadas à obra numa edição posterior, à qual se costuma incluir o sub-título "edição revista e corrigida".

Embora "errata" seja o plural de "erratum" em Latim, o uso no singular não parece ser comum.

> - [**Retratação**](https://www.dicio.com.br/retratacao/)
> - Pedido de desculpas; ação de se desculpar na tentativa de apagar o que foi dito ou feito anteriormente: consumidor exige retratação por injúria.
> - Desculpa; o que se diz para se desculpar: escreveu uma retratação à empresa.
> - Desmentido; confissão que desmente o conteúdo de uma anterior, assumindo ou reconhecendo um equívoco ou erro.